# Websocket can't connect but not throwing exceptions

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Trying to create a connection with websocket in JS to PHP server,
can't connect to the server but no exception thrown

**JS**

```
try {
    var socket;
    var host = "ws://www.somecoolsite.com:9080/test.php";
    var socket = new WebSocket(host);

    console.log("opening socket...");
    socket.onopen = function () {
        console.log('Socket Status: ' + socket.readyState + ' (open)');
        socket.send("2");
        console.log("sent first package");
    }

    socket.onconsole.log = function (msg) {
        console.log('Received: ' + msg.data);
    }

    socket.onclose = function () {
        console.log('Socket Status: ' + socket.readyState + ' (Closed)');
    }
} catch (exception) {
    console.log('Error' + exception);
}
```

**PHP on somecoolsite**

```
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:9080", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($server === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
} else {
    echo "Working";
}

for (;;) {
    $client = @stream_socket_accept($server);

    if ($client) {
        stream_copy_to_stream($client, $client);
        fclose($client);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this entire day, can't establish socket connection. Anyone has an idea what can be the problem here?

Comment: This doesn't help with the server side, but if you are expecting an exception in the client you won't get one.

WebSockets don't throw exceptions; there is an `onerror` handler.

`socket.onerror` gets called on any error, including a failure to connect to `host`.

Answer (score 0):

please remove this part of your code

```
socket.onconsole.log = function (msg) {
        console.log('Received: ' + msg.data);
    }
```

you can't do "socket.onconsole.log"

in my console i obtained a "Socket statut 3(closed)"

please take a look on this link

http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#websocket